# Rails how to create an independent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two objects `Task` and `Project` have an association `has_many` - `belongs_to`:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

**Task controller, method to create an associated object:**

```
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.build(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.js {}
        format.json { render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**View task#index, where a list of all tasks. Task controller method index:**

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.all
  @task= Task.new
end
```

How to create an independent object `Task` in this method?

**Error:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#create
Couldn't find Project with 'id'=
```

Can I create another method `create` and use it?

Comment: `Task.new`? Where do you want to create this 'independent' task?

Comment: @MarekLipka In the view `task#index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.all
  @task  = Task.new
end

def create
 @task = if params[:project_id]
   @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
   @project.tasks.build(task_params)
 else
   Task.new(task_params)
 end
 ...
```

Comment: Error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#create
Couldn't find Project with 'id'=`

Comment: What's the backtrace?

Comment: @AlexandrDmitrenko Error is about `TasksController#create`. You need to be able to create a task there independently of `project`. I will update my answer

Comment: @AzatGataoulline please tell me, how to add a `current_user `? I use `gem devise`, I need to add to the `user_id `in project using your example

Answer (score 3):

add the following lines to your **Project** Model.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks,
                      :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and in projects controller

```
private      
def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:name, ....., taks_attributes: [:id, .....,:_destroy])
end
```